# How to start process as a specific user on boot

Tags: arch-linux

*I am using Arch Linux.*

I need to start my web application automatically should the server should restart. I need to run it as user 'www'.

How can I do this?

Comment: To run a command as user `www` you could use:`sudo -u www some_command`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to write an [init script](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Writing_rc.d_scripts) for your web application.  (Examples for [Dropbox](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dropbox#Manual_Method) and [RTorrent](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RTorrent#Run_as_a_daemon).  You can find more examples if you [search the wiki for `add_daemon`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Special%3aSearch&search=add_daemon&fulltext=Search).)

Your script would use `su` to run the application as the appropriate user.  (Init scripts run as root, so they can `su` to any user.)

The critical line would look something like

```
su www -c "/path/of/app &"
```

Then you would add your new [daemon](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DAEMONS) to the DAEMONS list in [`/etc/rc.conf`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rc.conf), so it will be started automatically after booting.

Answer (score 5):

Use `su` to run it as the user, and put it into your `/etc/rc.local` to run it at boot.

```
su -c "start_server" www &
```